# NHibernate mappings with generic base classes

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using Fluent NHibernate to map my entities and I've come to a set that I'm having probelsm gettting mapped. I've tried different variations of SubclassMap but I can't seem to get Cart, Project or Order mapped correctly. Item, CartItem, OrderItem and ProjectItem map fine. I'm fairly new to NHibernate and I just can't figure out how to tell it to do what I want.

**EDIT:** This is the schema I'm going for with this inheritance structure:[image]

```
public abstract class Item
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual decimal Price {get;set;}
}

public class CartItem : Item
{
    public virtual string ProjectName {get;set;}
}

public class OrderItem : Item
{
    public virtual IList<Payment> Payments {get;set;}
}

public class ProjectItem : Item
{
    public virtual string ProjectName {get;set;}
}

public abstract class ItemCollection<T> where T: Item
{
    public virutal IList<T> Items {get;set;}
}

public abstract class CommerceCollection<T> : ItemCollection<T> where T : Item
{
    public virtual decimal Total {get;set;}
}

public class Project : ItemCollection<ProjectItem> 
{
    public virtual string ProjectName {get;set;}
}

public class Cart : CommerceCollection<CartItem> {}

public class Order : CommerceCollection<OrderItem>
{
    public virtual string OrderTrackingNumber {get;set;}
}

/*-------  MAPS  -------*/
public class ItemMap: ClassMap<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        MapId();
        Map(x=> x.Price);
    }
}

public class OrderItemMap : SubclassMap<OrderItem>
{
    public OrderItemMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.OrderItemProperty);
    }
}

public class CartItemMap : SubclassMap<CartItem>
{
    public CartItemMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.CartItemProperty);
    }
}

public class ProjectItemMap : SubclassMap<ProjectItem>
{
    public ProjectItemMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.ProjectItemProperty);
    }
}

 public class CartMap : ClassMap<Cart>
    {
        public CartMap()
        {
            Map(x => x.Total);
            HasMany(x => x.Items);
        }
    } 

    public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
    {
        public OrderMap()
        {
            Map(x => x.Total);
            HasMany(x => x.Items);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems that Cart, Project and Order are not inherited from Item. Is it correct?

Comment: That's correct, Cart Project and Order all have collections of Item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I needed to do. For the classes that implemented the generic base class (CommerceCollection) I had to add a map for the generic collection with it's argument and then specify the KeyColumn property on the subclass.

Here is the new CartMap:

```
public class CartCollectionMap : CommerceCollectionMap<CartItem> {}

    public class CartMap: SubclassMap<Cart>
    {
        public CartMap()
        {
            KeyColumn("CommerceCollection_id");
        }
    }
```

Nhibernate was generating SQL like below which would fail on the ' in the column name.

```
CREATE TABLE Cart (CommerceCollection'1_id int PRIMARY KEY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a simplified version of your mapping? If not:

1. Your SubclassMappings are missing a call to `KeyColumn("Item_id");` (this is needed to get a table-per-subclass mapping).
2. Your HasMany calls are missing a call like `.KeyColumn("Cart_id")`.

Comment: This is a simplified mapping.